# Magento 2 : How to add more page that can be accessed if Website Restrictions is on

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-2.1, website-restriction

How can i add more pages that can be accessed  like a `contact us` page with website restriction turned on

**UPDATE**

Found a file **\vendor\magento\module-website-restriction\etc\webrestrictions.xml**

How would i add my action to that xml **without editing core file**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom-module , create a file `\etc\webrestrictions.xml`
and add the required action path

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_WebsiteRestriction:etc/webrestrictions.xsd">

    <action path="customer_account_createpost" type="register" />
</config>
```

Comment: I have the website restrictions set to website closed and I'm trying to allow access to https://example.com/newsletter/subscriber/new/. I'm using path="newsletter_manage_index" but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?